# Generate recursive repetition list of text lines

Tags: text-processing

How to Expand text file:

Original text file:

```
1
2
3
4
5
etc
```

required expansion result:

```
1
2
3
4
5
2
3
4
5
6
3
4
5
6
7
etc.
```

that is list first 5 lines from file1 into new expansion file2, than append second block of 5 starting from n+1, then third block starting from n+2 and so on recursively till end of file1

Comment: Homework assignment?

Comment: Is that really recursive, or just iterative? What have you tried so far, and what were the results?

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I am not able to answer on the iterative vs recursive, I am no programmer. Only thing I could do myself is iteratevely cut and paste blocks of line, which is boring to say the least. I was hoping for some awk or sed or paste  magic. Basically I would like to turn a set of sentences into a spaced repetition adding a new sentence after every 5

Answer (score 1):

Just run this single line, once:

```
awk 'NR>5{printf"%s",out;sub("^[^\n]+\n","",out)}{out=out$0"\n"}END{printf "%s",out}' file
```

1. Replace `file` with the name of your file, of course.
2. `awk` is a program that proceeds through input line-by-line and does "stuff" to it.
3. `out=out$0\n` creates a variable `out` and appends the current line to it, followed by a newline character.
4. `NR>5{...}` means "do the stuff in braces for records (eg. lines) greater than line #5.
5. `printf "%s", out` prints the variable `out`.
6. `sub("^[^\n]+\n","",out)` is a substitution command used here as a deletion command, replacing the beginning of `out` until the first newline character with an empt string.
7. To save the output to a second file `file2`, add at the end of the line "> file2".

UPDATE:

There does exist another tool, called `sed` a *stream editor*, which produces a shorter, but much more cryptic solution:

```
 sed -n '6,${x;p;s/^[^\n]\+\n//;x};H;1h;${x;p}' file
```

1. `1h` puts the first line in the 'hold' space.
2. `H` appends lines to the hold space.
3. `6,${x;p;s/^[^\n]\+\n//;x}`, starting at line 6, swaps the hold space with the current line, prints it, removes the first line, and sends the result back to the hold space.
4. ${x;p}, at the end of processing, bring back the hold space (could have been a `g` instead of an `x`), and print it.

Comment: Thank you all for your effort. I am in awe. However, I guess Ishould have mentioned that the lines in the file are structured as:

Comment: @sky36043: Umm,you *still* haven't mentioned that... Explain it as an edit to your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
# get number of lines in the file
n=$( wc -l <file )

# extend the file
awk -v n="$n" 'NR <= n { print $1+1 >>FILENAME }' file
```

Run these two commands as many times as you wish.

The `awk` program simply appends lines to the same file that it's reading from. The data appended will be the existing numbers incremented by one.

If we don't limit this by the number of lines in the file (with `NR <= n`), it will grow indefinitely, until it fills up the partition.

Answer (score 0):

Given an `input` file of `seq 10 > input`:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

The following will loop through the lines of the file, printing each block of 5:

```
n=$(wc -l < input)
for((i=1; i <= n-4; i++)); do sed -n "$i,$((i+4))p" < input; done
```

Resulting in:

```
1
2
3
4
5
2
3
4
5
6
3
4
5
6
7
4
5
6
7
8
5
6
7
8
9
6
7
8
9
10
```